Why is my Ui moving faster and faster with SmoothDamp? Unity | Animation | SmoothDamp
So i was working on a Animation per code. I didnt wanted to use the in Build Unity Editor. I decided SmoothDamp would be the perfect solution for my code, or so i thought. Because after some game testing i noticed my Ui is moving faster and faster everytime i restart the Courutine. I tried to implement Lerp but the code looked so clampy everytime i build it that it worked with Lerp and i didnt have any curve i it. I guess its because the SmoothDamp takes a velocity but how can I fix this issue ?
thanks for helping and reading..
this i add on every GameObject what will have an interaction Option
public class PlayerActionHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private Vector3 interactionSize;
[SerializeField] PlayerActionController controller;

private void Start() {
    setUpTrigger();
}

public void Test(float test) {
    print(test);
}

private void setUpTrigger() {
    if (controller.interactionObject == null) controller.interactionObject = gameObject;
    GameObject interactionObject = controller.interactionObject;
    BoxCollider trigger = interactionObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
    trigger.isTrigger = true;
    trigger.size = interactionSize;
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c) {
    PlayerMovementController p = c.GetComponent<PlayerMovementController>();
    if (p == null) return;
    StartCoroutine(controller.actionFieldEnter());
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider c) {
    PlayerMovementController p = c.GetComponent<PlayerMovementController>();
    if (p == null) return;
    StopCoroutine(controller.actionFieldEnter());
    Destroy(controller.parent);
    Destroy(controller.iImage.gameObject);
}

}

and thats the controller to handle the animation
[Serializable]
public class PlayerActionController {

[SerializeField] private Key key;
[SerializeField] public GameObject interactionObject;
[SerializeField] private Vector3 sizeOfInteractionHelper = Vector3.one;
[SerializeField] private EventHandler keyAction;

[NonSerialized] public GameObject parent;
[NonSerialized] public Image iImage;

private float animationOffset = 0.1f;
private Vector3 vel = Vector3.zero;
private Vector3 iOffset;

public bool createUi() {
    parent = new GameObject("InterActionMenu");
    Canvas pCanvas = parent.AddComponent<Canvas>();
    RectTransform scaler = parent.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    scaler.sizeDelta = sizeOfInteractionHelper;
    pCanvas.worldCamera = Camera.main;
    parent.AddComponent<CanvasScaler>();
    parent.AddComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();

    GameObject interactionImage = new GameObject("InteractionImage");
    interactionImage.transform.parent = parent.transform;
    iImage = interactionImage.AddComponent<Image>();
    iImage.sprite = key.keySprite;
    iImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta = sizeOfInteractionHelper;
    iImage.color = Color.white;

    return true;
}

public IEnumerator actionFieldEnter() {

    yield return new WaitUntil(() => createUi());

    iOffset = new Vector3(0, interactionObject.transform.localScale.y + 0.2f + animationOffset, 0);
    parent.transform.position = interactionObject.transform.position + iOffset;

    while (!Input.GetKeyDown(key.actionKey)) {
        controlAnimation();
        yield return null;
    }
}

private void controlAnimation() {
    if (parent == null && iImage == null) return;
    PlayerActionHandler dsa = new PlayerActionHandler();
    dsa.Test(MathF.Round(parent.transform.position.y, 1));
    if (MathF.Round(parent.transform.position.y, 1) == MathF.Round(interactionObject.transform.position.y + iOffset.y, 1)) {
        toogleAnimation(-animationOffset);
    }
    else toogleAnimation(animationOffset);
}

private void toogleAnimation(float _offset) {
    animationOffset = _offset;
    iOffset = new Vector3(0, interactionObject.transform.localScale.y + 0.2f + animationOffset, 0);
    parent.transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(parent.transform.position, interactionObject.transform.position + iOffset, ref vel, 1.2f);
}

}


It's hard to tell from your code, but it seems like your interactionObject reference is actually set to either the same object this script is attached to or a child of some sort. As a result the position of the interactionObject will change when you move the parent. So it's impossible to ever reach that position. SmoothDamp will slowly ramp up the velocity in order to get closer to the target object and based on the remaining distance will also ramp it back down again. However since the remaining distance does never change (because your target moves with your object) the velocity keeps increasing.
It's hard to tell what the actual goal is. When you have such dynamic positions you need to be more careful which object depends on which other object. Having a circular dependency is not a good idea.
